# Heroku Django ApplicationError: 'module' has no attribute 'TemporaryDirectory'

Tags: python, django, heroku, temporary-files

In a django app I have hosted on Heroku, I have one view that generates a PDF from a LaTeX template, and stores it as a temporary file. The view is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import tempfile
import os

def pdf(request):
    context = Context({})
    template = get_template('cv/simple.tex')
    rendered_tpl = template.render(context).encode('utf-8')  
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir: ## ERROR RAISED HERE ##
        process = Popen(
            ['pdflatex', '-output-directory', tempdir],
            stdin=PIPE,
            stdout=PIPE,
        )
        process.communicate(rendered_tpl)
        with open(os.path.join(tempdir, 'texput.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
            pdf = f.read()
    r = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')  
    r.write(pdf)
    return r
```

This works fine locally. However, when I push it to Heroku and try to visit the URL pointed at the view, I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /cv.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/cv/views.py", line 34, in pdf
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TemporaryDirectory'
```

Other questions for similar errors suggest that it may be due to one having a script call `tempfile.py` that gets imported instead of the python library, but I don't have one (unless Heroku does). Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TemporaryDirectory](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) added in Python 3.2. You should update Python to use this function.